# Multiple properties-files for CAS 4.2.2

Tags: java, spring, cas

i'm updating our CAS 4.0.0 to CAS 4.2.2. Everything works fine, but i'm not able to load more than one properties-file.

The `propertyFileConfigurer.xml` by default looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <description>...</description>

    <util:properties id="casProperties" location="file:///c:/path/to/cas.properties"/>
    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="casProperties"/>

</beans>
```

The `<util:properties id="casProperties"/>` is hardwired and must exsist.

How do I extend this file with an other properties file?

I tried this (no warnings or errors) but without success. LDAP properties are not replaced:

```
<bean id="casProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>file:///c:/path/to/cas.properties</value>
      <value>file:///c:/path/to/ldap.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="casProperties" order="1"/>
```

There is no example for multiple properties-files in the documentation and beeing not familiar with Java makes try-and-error really hard.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit late for you but I came accross your question while looking up the same issue myself, and have been able to use more than one properties file with this:

```
<util:properties id="casProperties" location="file:/etc/cas/cas.properties,file:/etc/cas/ldap.properties" />
```